# How to do pageViewController tap selection UI?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

In my app I have a pageViewController with 5 pages.I need the page selector to look like the image below.

[image]

currently I am using the following code to select the tab selector.

```
-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
    if (!completed) {
        return;
    }
    if(completed)
    {
        [self setTabTextColor:nextIndex];


    }
}
```

and ***it works***.**but here I am creating 5 white tab selectors(uiviews below the respective texts) in the storyboard and  displaying one at a time**.

I know this is not the currect way of doing this.Is there a custom controller to do the same?

or if I am doing it wrong,please let me know the correct way.

> In  android,I have seen that if we are doing the pageviewcontroller
>   swipe ,the selector animates with it automatically and resizes itself
>   to fit the current text width.anybody have any idea to do the same?

Comment: check this....https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tabview

Comment: Use `Auto Layout`.In code, you can modify `constant` property to dynamically change white indicator's width and left margin.

Answer (score 1):

it's simple , i think this will help you to get started

1.first create pageViewController

```
    mPageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:@{UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.0f]}]; //mPageViewController is a property of type UIPageViewController

    [mPageViewController setViewControllers:@[theVC] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    mPageViewController.dataSource = self;

    mPageViewController.delegate = self;

    mPageViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;

    [self addChildViewController:mPageViewController];

    [self.view addSubview:mPageViewController.view];

    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:mPageViewController.view];



2. then implement it's delegate methods

        - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc viewControllerBeforeViewController:(YourViewController *)viewController
        { // take on mPageIndex property in your controller to detect current index

            if (viewController.mPageIndex > 0) {

            YourViewController * theVC = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
            theVC.mPageIndex=viewController.mPageIndex-1;
            return theVC;
        }

        return nil;
        }

        - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc viewControllerAfterViewController:(PhotoViewController *)viewController
       {
            if (viewController.mPageIndex < mControllerListArray.count-1) {

        YourViewController * theVC = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
        theVC.mPageIndex=viewController.mPageIndex+1; // mPageIndex is propety of type int to detect current page
        return theVC;
    }

        return nil;
}


-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
        {
        if (completed) {

            NSUInteger currentIndex = [[mPageViewController.viewControllers lastObject] mPageIndex];

            mPageIndex = (int)currentIndex;

            [self updateUI];

       }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.buit this is an old question.I used carbon kit to implement this. https://github.com/abhimuralidharan/CCkitTest-iOS